# How to obtain a list of all build-in system level Heads?

Tags: core-language, head

I am writing a small Mathematical expression parser and need a list of all Mathematica build-in Heads (system context?) so I can check the type of input.

Such as `List`,`Integer`,`Times`,`Plus`,`Rational`,`Symbol`,`Real`,`Sin`,`Cos` ,`Power`,`Equal`, and so on. i.e. those names which return from the command `Head[..]`. This does not include user level expressions ofcourse. Only system level `Heads`, obtained from Fresh kernel.

I googled and could not find an answer. May be this is something that can be obtained [WolframLanguageData](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html) ? But I never used this, and when I looked at it, I did not see how to ask it for this.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/blob/develop/resources/de/halirutan/mathematica/codeinsight/completion/symbolVersions.properties) and maybe [here](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/blob/develop/resources/mathematica/FunctionInformation.m).

Comment: ``Names["System`*"]`` may help, but it gives you ALL symbols, not just those which are used in a "functional" form, i.e. function[...].

Comment: @JEM_Mosig yes I know this command. But I need only names of `Heads`, not all system level names. Many of the names listed there I do not think are names of Heads. For example `$SoundDisplayFunction` is listed from the above command. But is this a name of a Head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a list with

```
Select[
 Names["System`*"],
 Quiet[
   With[{
     dv = ToExpression[#, InputForm, DownValues],
     expr = ToExpression[#, InputForm]
     },
    dv =!= {} && MemberQ[dv, HoldPattern[expr[__]], \[Infinity]]
    ]
   ] &
 ]
```

I am not entirely sure if this is complete, but it is a starting point.

Alternatively you can hope that the usage string of any function starts with "f[...] ...". There is no guarantee, but it seems to be this way. Then you can use

```
Table[
 With[{usage = WolframLanguageData[sym, "PlaintextUsage"]},
  If[
   StringQ[usage],
   If[StringMatchQ[usage, sym ~~ "[" ~~ Except["]"] ~~ __], sym, 
    Nothing],
   Nothing
   ]
  ],
 {sym, Names["System`*"]}
 ]
```

Note, however, that this is very slow! I have done it with the first 200 symbols from `` Names["System`*"] `` and it took about 20 seconds.